# Angular 6 Http Request Json Headers Doesn't Works

Tags: angular

I'm just trying to make a post using Angular 6 HttpClient, but the problem is that it doesn't send the data if HttpHeaders is in the options params.
That just happens with 'Content-Type': 'application/json'.

AuthComponentTS:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {

  httpOptions = {headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })};
  api = 'http://localhost:3000/api/login';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  login(form): Observable<any> {
    const body = JSON.stringify(form);
    console.log(form);
    return this.http.post<any>(this.api, body, this.httpOptions);
  }

  authenticationHandler(): boolean {
    const token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
    return !token;
  }
}
```

LoginComponentTS:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from '../../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  hide = true;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  login(form): void {
    this.authService.login(form.value)
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

}
```

LoginComponentHTML:

```
<div class="position-absolute d-flex w-100 h-100">
  <div class="container m-auto">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-10 col-sm-8 m-auto p-3">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="../../../../src/assets/img/logo.png">
        </div>
        <form #form="ngForm" action="javascript:void(0)" (submit)="login(form)">
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput name="username" ngModel placeholder="Digite seu usuário">
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput name="password" ngModel placeholder="Digite sua senha" [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'">
            <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">{{hide ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>
          </mat-form-field>
          <div class="text-center">
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">
              Login
            </button>
            {{form.value | json}}
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Request From Angular (Failed! Always Pending):
[image: Angular Request]

Request From Postman (Works just fine):
[image: Postman Request]

I appreciate for helps!

Comment: PS: Posting in postman works just fine...

Comment: You mean the `login` function is working fine before without an `httpOptions`? Because I think you are having a problem with your `body` since you `stringify` it and putted inside your http post parameter. try to `return this.http.post<any>(this.api, form, this.httpOptions)`

Comment: I have tried it already... I mean: I can post using another format like: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: then? what happen? can you please add your code where you are calling the login?

Comment: There we go... I have been updated the post.

Comment: Ohh, I think this link may help you on how to use the Angular HTTP Post Service https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#add-heroserviceaddhero

Comment: Specifying the json content type and stringifying the body is unnecessary. HttpClient does that for you.

Comment: and send httpHeaders 'Content-Type': 'application/json' is also unnecesary.

Comment: I have tried without headers, then it sends the data null :(